# HttpClient post withcredentials not working in ionic ios app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cookies, httpclient, capacitor

So I was trying to run my ionic app on an iOS simulator. Unfortunately, it seems like the cookies are not persisting and I get 401 on subsequent requests. I am using Angular's HttpClient to send the post request and it works just fine on the browsers across all platforms. CORS has been enabled on my backend service. Does anyone have any idea about where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and switched to the latest hardware support with capacitor.

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core'
const { Http } = Plugins
```

The developer site: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http